# Replace content of iframe after doing data processing via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, iframe, dom-manipulation

I've following function for getting HTML template from server and replacing some tags

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/newsletter/preview/1",
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        var template = data;
        var layer = $("<iframe>").attr({ "id": "preview_frame" });
        $("#newsletter .element input, #newsletter .element textarea").each(function() {
            var id = "\\$\\$"+$(this).parent().parent().attr("id").replace(/^newsletter_/, "")+"\\$\\$";
            template = template.replace(new RegExp(id, "g"), htmlspecialchars($(this).val(),2));
        });
        $("body").prepend(layer);
    },
    dataType: "html"
});
```

Getting the template works fine. Also replacing the tags with content of form (when placing `alert(escape(template));` inside `each` loop shows me, that all tags are being replaced). But there are two unsolved problems yet:

- I didn't find a way to set content of variable `template` into iframe
  (`$("#preview_frame").contents().find("body").html(template);`
  results only in an empty frame)
- Prepending the iframe (variable `layer`) to the HTML body happens
  during iterating through form fields, but it has to be done after(!)
  all tags have been replaced, so that only the complete processed template is going to be placed inside the iframe.

Comment: you couldnt set iframe content by that way.

Comment: I thought so, already. But what could be a solution? It doesn't has to be an iframe. But the HTML contains full CSS and so on, so I thought iframe would be best way to view HTML and have no conflict with CSS from main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using now form plugin for jQuery from http://malsup.com/jquery/form/.
So I'm sending form via Ajax to server, which generates temporary file that is included via iframe after successful sending form.

Answer (score 0):

add an ifame dynamicly which source is your ajax call url, and do the javascript things in onload of your iframe page.

```
$("<iframe/>").attr({
   source: "/newsletter/preview/1",
   id: "preview_frame"
}).appendTo($("body"));
```

Comment: if you wanna use iframe for no html and css conflicts this should be ok

Comment: So replacing tags have to be done inside iframe via JS? That's impossible, because I cannot place JS code inside the template.